# How to change the name of a cookie in cakephp 3.x

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.x

So basically the question is that, how to change the name of the cookie that Auth method creates once you login to the site.

Answer (score 0):

I did not found the docs a straight answer to it but here it is. What it is, is a little overriding of the default one used by CAKEPHP, that is all. Hope it helps to anyone. Cheers

in the config/bootstrap.php I added the following code.

```
    Configure::write('Session', [
        'defaults' => 'php',
        'cookie'=>'YOUR-COOKIE-NAME',
    ]);
```

Comment: [Here](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/sessions.html#session-configuration) is where this is discussed in the documentation.

Comment: That is true, but is not specified in which file you can set it up, in my case I found out it is in config/bootstrap.php

Comment: The very first line of the referenced documentation reads "Session configuration is generally defined in `/config/app.php`". `bootstrap.php` can work too, but I think `app.php` is a more natural fit.